# PHP, JS and codeigniter script with if else statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am working on a simple code for a scoreboard and need a little help. I have the scoreboard performing the right score calculation, however when I try to come up with level system with the number above, I am not able to get it to execute right.

So bacially I want this to say, If playerScore.score is less than or = to 100, then your PlayerScore.Level is 1. Else if playerscore.score is greater than or = 101 but less than 200, then Playerscore.level is 2. I am actually doing about 10 levels, but if I can just get the first one to go, I should be good to get the other. any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
"script_fields": {
      "PlayerScore.score": {
         "script": "if (doc['PlayerScore.deathCount'].value == 0) { doc['PlayerScore.playerKills'].value } else { Math.round(2 * doc['PlayerScore.playerKills'].value + doc['PlayerScore.aiKills'].value + (5 * doc['PlayerScore.captureCount'].value))}"
      }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "PlayerScore.level": {
   "script": "if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 100) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 1) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 300) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 2) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 500) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 3) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 900) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 4) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 1400) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 5) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 2000) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 6) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 2700) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 7) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 3500) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 8) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value <= 5000) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 9) }
          else if (doc['PlayerScore.score'].value >= 7500) { (doc['PlayerScore.level'].value = 10) }"
    }
},
```

So the first script field calculates the score which works correctly and outputs it to a column in a table, the second one, just cant seem to get it right.

Comment: This appears to be JSON. How are you intending to use this JavaScript that's arbitrarily stored in there? It'd probably be better to send the rules for each level as a normal data structure rather than ship code: `[ 0, 100, 300, 500, 900, 1400, .. ]` as the level definitions. There's zero need for code here. Ridiculous levels of repetition are usually a sign of an inelegant solution.

Comment: This is JSON and I am new to JSON and basically building on another person's code.

Comment: Before anyone slams me, I do have permission from the owner :-)

Comment: Just ship the relevant values and have a client-side script that evaluates them. JSON really should not have JavaScript in it, it's intended for data.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way to solve the issue.
However using "if" with all statements instead of elseif would solve your issue.